# Matching an object somewhere in a Scala List

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm trying to pattern match on a Scala list with a pattern that will match if an object of the desired type is contained anywhere within the list.

I tried:

```
case _ :: (something: DesiredSubclass) :: _ => ???
```

But this only matches if there is at least one element before the one that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use of overt `isInstanceOf[SomeType]` is unsightly. Using the `match`-like `PartialFunction` literal notation is preferable:

```
list.exists { case _: DesiredSubclass => true; case _ => false }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use an `if` guard along with the `exists` higher order method.

```
case xs if xs.exists(_.isInstanceOf[DesiredSubclass]) => ???
```

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching can't be used to do arbitrary searches like that.  You can

```
list.collect{ case something: DesiredSubclass => something }.headOption
```

to get an option with the item in it.  You can't assign this within the match statement, but if it's really important to get that particular class, you can write a custom extractor:

```
class DesiredSubclass(val s: String) {}
object FirstOfDesired {
  def unapply[A](xs: Seq[A]) = xs.collect{ case x: DesiredSubclass => x }.headOption
}
```

Now, for example:

```
val list = 7 :: (new DesiredSubclass("fish")) :: Nil
scala> list match { case FirstOfDesired(ds) => println(ds.s); case _ => }
fish
```